# Why doesn't GeneTag use BIO for its annotations?

Tags: computational-linguistics, corpora, named-entity-recognition, annotation

GeneTag (1) is a tagged corpus for gene/protein named entity recognition.

The corpus is annotated as follows:

> P00089778A0000 
> The_TAG concentration_TAG of_TAG alpha_GENE1 2_GENE1
>   -_GENE1 macroglobulin_GENE1 ,_TAG alpha_GENE2 1_GENE2 -_GENE2 antitrypsin_GENE2 ,_TAG plasminogen_GENE1 ,_TAG C3_GENE2 -_GENE2
>   complement_GENE2 ,_TAG fibrinogen_GENE1 degradation_GENE1
>   products_GENE1 (_TAG FDP_GENE2 )_TAG and_TAG fibrinolytic_TAG
>   activity_TAG [...]

The corpus is stored as a list of instances each consisting of (a) an identifier on the first line, and (b) a sequence of tokens on the second line. Each token is of the form word tag where tag can be one of {TAG, GENE1, GENE2}. *TAG* represents any word that is not part of a gene name, while *GENE1* and *GENE2* mean the token is part of a gene name. The index 1 and 2 just works as indicators to distinguish two dierent but adjacent
gene names.

Why not using the BIO notation (or something [similar](http://lingpipe-blog.com/2009/10/14/coding-chunkers-as-taggers-io-bio-bmewo-and-bmewo/))? E.g.:

> P00089778A0000 
>   The_O concentration_O of_O alpha_B 2_I -_I
>   macroglobulin_I ,_O alpha_B 1_I -_I antitrypsin_I ,_O plasminogen_I
>   ,_O C3_B -_I complement_I ,_O fibrinogen_B degradation_I  products_I
>   (_O FDP_B )_O and_O fibrinolytic_O activity_O [...]

---

(1) Tanabe, Lorraine, et al. "[GENETAG: a tagged corpus for gene/protein named entity recognition.](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=1214544014446255107&hl=en&as_sdt=0,22)" BMC bioinformatics 6.Suppl 1 (2005): S3.

Comment: But why should it?

Comment: @curiousdannii if you train a tagger on it, say an HMM or CRF, you'll have two classes gene1 and gene2, while it would make more sense to have a class begin and a class inside. Also BIO is pretty much the standard de facto for NER annotations.